# get error in filter name with regex android

Tags: android, regex

I would to allow user to enter name, allow them to use this character" a to z, A to Z, 0 to 9, comma, space, underscore, dash" only. here is my code...

```
Pattern pattern_checkName = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_-,//s//.]{3,}$");
Matcher matcher = pattern_checkName.matcher(para);
return matcher.matches();
```

And I got this error, regex syntax error:

```
06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: In a character range [x-y], x is greater than y near index 
14:06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735): ^[a-zA-Z0-9_-,//s//.]{3,}$
06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):   
        ^
06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)

06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)

06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)

06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)

06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at com.elite.mm.util.Util.checkName(Util.java:103)

06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at com.elite.mm.ActivityRegister$1.onClick(ActivityRegister.java:89)

06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)

 06-19 14:27:29.653: E/AndroidRuntime(7735):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all when you use `-` within your character class your regex engine assume it as a **text range** if you want to match it literary you need to put it at the end of character class.

Also if you want to match white-space you need `\s` so you can use following regex :

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_,\s//.-]{3,}$"
```

And more precise instead of `a-zA-Z0-9_` you can sue `\w` that match any word character, and use space instead of white-space also if you don't want use dot you should remove it from your character class :

```
"^[\w, /-]{3,}$"
```